# Android / Java - MultiAutoCompleteTextView returns null - Causes FATAL NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, fatal-error, multiautocompletetextview

I have a Calendar within my Android app which implements MultiAutoCompleteTextView:

```
MultiAutoCompleteTextView mAttendeesList;
```

...

```
mAttendeesListView = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.scheduling_attendee_list);
```

View Class's source (if necessary):
http://pastebin.com/rneiF4d1

The problem is - when attempting to create a listener for it in another class it continually returns null when the listener is implemented as shown below:

```
private void initChangeListeners() {
    clearChangeListeners();

    if (mViewListener == null) {
      mViewListener = new RecipientTextWatcher(mView, mViewListener);
    }
 //TO FIX  (equals null) 
    mAttendeesList.addTextChangedListener(mViewListener);

}
```

Activity source (if necessary):
http://pastebin.com/iAgSpjFd

The end result is:

```
01-28 03:15:54.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 03:15:54.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 03:15:54.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2730):     at com.android.calendar.event.EditEventActivity.initChangeListeners(EditEventActivity.java:178)
```

which (just fyi) is mAttendeesList returing null here:

```
mAttendeesList.addTextChangedListener(mViewListener);
```

Comment: Where are you initializing mAttendeesList?

Comment: initMultiAutoCompleteTextView((RecipientEditTextView) mAttendeesList);

inside EditEventView.java:

http://pastebin.com/rneiF4d1

Comment: Show full code, that will help more in understanding the flow.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iAgSpjFd
http://pastebin.com/rneiF4d1

I think that should be all you need.

Comment: is `mAttendeesList` == null?

Comment: In EditEventActivity mAttendeesList it is null - in EditEventView it is not null

Comment: How you are accessing the mAttendeeList in the 'EditEventActivity' because its the member of EditEventView Class ?

Comment: I believe that is what I need assistance with (since it is returning null)

Comment: Steven Schultz check my answer below.

Comment: Generally all uncaught NullPointerExceptions are FATAL.

Answer (score 0):

Make the object of the `EditEventView` Class and also make the `mAttendeeList` view `public`, then access it like this-

```
EditEventView editEventViewObject = new EditEventView(pass all the parameters which you have declared in its constructor);
editEventViewObject.mAttendeeList.addTextChangedListener(mViewListener);
```

This will surely help.

Comment: EditEventView editEventViewObject = new EditEventView(Activity activity, View view, EditDoneRunnable done,
                boolean timeSelectedWasStartTime, boolean dateSelectedWasStartDate);

is causing me errors...

Comment: What kind of errors? You have to pass the parameters according to the constructor signature of class EditEventView.

Comment: - Syntax error on token "view", delete this token
        - Syntax error on token "done", delete this token
        - View cannot be resolved to a variable
        - Syntax error on token "activity", delete this
         token
        - Activity cannot be resolved to a variable
        - EditDoneRunnable cannot be resolved to a
         variable


The parameters I'm attempting to pass (which I believe match the constructor) can be found here: http://pastebin.com/CxeGjJQS

Comment: Shouldn't your answer look more like this? 

EditEventView editEventViewObject;
        editEventViewObject.mAttendeesList.addTextChangedListener(mViewListener);

Comment: Activity Class Source:  http://pastebin.com/CmXR5tte

 View Class Source: http://pastebin.com/wJDPKNPF

Comment: It would be something like this-
EditEventView editEventViewObject = new EditEventView(EditEventActivity.this, view, done, true or false, true or false);

Comment: Error: 
EditEventActivity.java:180: variable done might not have been initialized
  EditEventView 


FULL SOURCE: 


https://www.zerobin.net/?5b874a7df4096ca7#h0eAphQzr/mC8jGmU2JofMOEOGXPvX89EBz9jKFPuTA=

Comment: No, its not that much difficult. You are not able to initialize the object correclty. Their is another way, don't make the object. In the EditEventView class, make 'mAttendeeList' static and then in the activity class access it like this- EditEventView.mAttendeesList.addTextChangedListener(mViewListener);

Comment: I'm actually getting a NPE / Fatal Error at the line: EditEventView.mAttendeesList.addTextChangedListener(mViewListener);

Any idea why? 




EditEventView:

https://www.zerobin.net/?01b1103072aa9e26#jHbF13Rl0B1bfw0GbU3DeleyzQIWydWQKTzvkLf9CeI=

EditEventActivity:

https://www.zerobin.net/?59ad53740e45f792#p9iZI4S/d/5uZvniJnQjMwLJsHXQWHekA/F5HxRWGSI=